# how to execute SOAP UI test cases with command line

Tags: command-line, automation, soapui

Currently in our project we have automated SOAP UI test cases. Our requirement is to run these automated scripts from command line. So is there anyway to generate a batch program to execute these instead of running from the soap GUI?

Thanks,
Kumar

Comment: Have you checked the solution? If that is helpful, appreciate accept it as answered.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is very much possible.

SoapUI provides utilities under `SOAPUI_HOME/bin` directory.

`testrunner.bat( or.sh)` utility helps to execute the project command line. This has various options as well.

For more details, refer [documentation](https://www.soapui.org/test-automation/running-from-command-line/functional-tests.html).

Answer (score 0):

To be more specific about [Rao](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1702943/rao)'s answer, you need to run testrunner.bat(or .sh) file from a terminal. For example, in Windows, open cmd program. Then in the command line, change directory to the bin folder (e.g. `c:\> cd "c:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-Pro-5.1.2\bin"`). Now you can run testrunner file to execute your test from command line. To see options run `> testrunner.bat` or `>testrunner.sh`.